# Subtract date jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've tried to subtract between two dates. Date "a" and Date "b" using this code that I've found here. It works with jsfiddle.net but not with my project.

This is my code :
HTML and JS

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#startdate,#enddate").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    firstDay: 1,
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
  })

  $("#startdate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
  });
  $("#enddate").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
  });

  $('#enddate').change(function() {
    var start = $('#startdate').datepicker('getDate');
    var end = $('#enddate').datepicker('getDate');

    if (start < end) {
      var days = (end - start) / 1000 / 60 / 60 / 24;
      $('#days').val(days);
    } else {
      alert("You cant come back before you have been!");
      $('#startdate').val("");
      $('#enddate').val("");
      $('#days').val("");
    }
  }); //end change function
}); //end ready
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/0.6.5/datepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/0.6.5/datepicker.min.css">
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-md-3">date 1</label>
  <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-11">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="startdate">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-md-3">date 2</label>
  <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-11">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="enddate">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="control-label col-md-3">result</label>
  <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-11">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="days">
  </div>
</div>
```

But when I import into the project, it does not work. Like JS file not found the HTML's "id" or else. Can anyone help me ?

This is [The JSFIDDLE link](https://jsfiddle.net/rw3h4pq8/21/) to this query.

Comment: Any errors shown in browser console?  Just saying *"it's not work"* is a virtually useless technical problem statement that by itself tells us nothing of value

Comment: TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function pickers-init.js:71:1

http://localhost/aa/assets/js/pickers-init.js:71:1

but i use datepicker instead datetimepicker.

Comment: you should check the assets folder in pickers-init.js file line 71 as ertor states. I think it's not about code above

Comment: after fixed the errors, it keep not working.

Comment: i've tried it with other bootstrap themes and got the same result. only work with standar html code. i dont know what's the problem here

Answer (score -1):

it's working fine with me did you check in incognito mode? ctrl+shift+N and check in incognito

Comment: i did. that code not work with bootstrap. i've tried it with other bootstrap themes and got the same result. only work with standar html code. i dont know what's the problem here.